# Ruby on rails flash notice error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications, notice, rails-flash

I have a problem with `flash[:notice] = "Message"` in Ruby on Rails.

I am trying to create login fault error message. My login fault handling is:

```
flash[:notice] = "Invalid username/password combination."
redirect_to(:action => 'login')
```

For the reason I don't know, alert just doesn't show up. I have red tons of possible solutions, but all of them just doesn't work for me. I am using Safari / Google Chrome web browsers.

Comment: Where are you displaying flash messages in the view? What does your view look like?

Comment: No. In a controller. This alert is in a if statement and works if user is not authorised.

Comment: I think @ChrisPeters was asking you to basically show us how you're displaying the alerts in your HTML. If he wasn't, than I am :)

Comment: what is your view? how you are rending flash message?

Comment: Sorry, guys, I don't understand you... I have red, that flash is some kind of error alert. So, thats what I am doing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller code looks fine. I suspect your problem is *not* that you are calling the `flash` method incorrectly in your controller, but rather that you did not write the code (correctly) to display the flash in your view.

`flash` simply holds a message for your views to display. You are setting the message correctly, but you may not be displaying it properly. I can't tell because you aren't posting your view code.

For example, if this action is the result of submitting a `user/login.html.erb` form, based on your controller code, you would want to have the following code inside that view file:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

This code is a more basic version of what is described in [this article](https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/how-to-add-a-flash-message-to-your-rails-page/).